# How do i change the color of a line in itext?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I have drawn a rectangle in a pdf . Inside it i have drawn multiple lines . i want lines to appear in different colors as . for that i have written  following lines of code, but its not working.

All lines appear in black including recatngle drawn on pdf

```
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    try {

        cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, true), 24);
        cb.rectangle(0f,0f,842f,595f);
        cb.saveState();

    //  Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(56.69f,56.69f,737f,510.23f);
        final float bx=0f;
        float bX=842f;
        float by=0f;
        float bY=595f;
       float  x=14.17f;
        int count=0;

      float bXX=14.17f+bx;


         for(float k=0;k<842;k=k+x)
         {
             cb.moveTo(k+bx,by);
                cb.lineTo(k+bx,bY+bx); 

                cb.setLineWidth(7);
                cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.BLUE));

         }



        for(float i=0;i<595;i=i+x)
        {
            cb.moveTo(bx,by+i);
            cb.lineTo(bx+bX,i+by); 
            cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.RED));
        }



    //  ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,new Phrase("LEAD I"), 0,(12*graphHeight), 0);
        cb.restoreState();
        cb.stroke();


    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just check this answer. Hope it helps you. [iText](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19877623/2078074)

Comment: i am looking ,can it be done using PdfContentByte ,after all it behaves like a canvas. i dont want to  use separator @DhruvVaishnav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All lines are drawn at the moment you invoke the `stroke()` method, using the color that is "active" at that particular moment.

So if you do:

```
cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.RED));
cb.moveTo(x1, y1);
cb.lineTo(x2, y2);
cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.BLUE));
cb.moveTo(x3, y3);
cb.lineTo(x4, y4);
cb.stroke();
```

This is illegal syntax, because once you've started constructing a path, only other path construction operations, a clipping operation, and (finally) a drawing operation is allowed before you change the state. Nevertheless, most PDF viewer will tolerate syntax errors like this: the lines from `x1, y1` to `x2, y2`and from `x3, y3` to `x4, y4` will be drawn in blue because that's the current graphics state at the moment the `stroke` operation is performed.

If you want the line from `x1, y1` to `x2, y2` to be drawn in red, you need to insert another `stroke()` operation:

```
cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.RED));
cb.moveTo(x1, y1);
cb.lineTo(x2, y2);
cb.stroke();
cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.BLUE));
cb.moveTo(x3, y3);
cb.lineTo(x4, y4);
cb.stroke();
```

In your code, your `setColorStroke()` operations, don't have any effect, because you're using `saveState()` and `restoreState()` incorrectly:

```
// you save the current graphics state: e.g. stroke color is black.
cb.saveState();
// you change the stroke color: it is now blue
cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.BLUE));
// you return to the graphics state from before saveState:
cb.restoreState();
// the stroke color is now black again
// all changes to the graphics state after saveState() are rolled back
```

You should reorganize the way you save and restore the graphics state and you should draw the lines and shapes in the color you've just defined *before* changing those colors to something else again.

Comment: Strictly speaking the first example (and even more so the OP's code) is invalid: As soon as you start to create a path, only other path creating instructions until an optional clip path setting and a mandatory path drawing instruction. Thus, `cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.BLUE))` is invalid. PDF viewer usually accept it nonetheless...

Comment: @mkl I'll update my answer to inform other readers that they shouldn't use that snippet.

Comment: @mkl what do you mean cb.setColorStroke(new BaseColor(Color.BLUE)) is invalid. do you mean if i print in A4 sheet it wont take?

Comment: @abh22ishek See the update to my answer. You are not respecting the rules of ISO-32000-1. There's a logical sequence: **(1)** change the graphics state (color, line width,...), **(2)** construct the path (line to, move to, rectangle,...), **(3)** draw the path (fill, stroke,...). You are mixing things up by changing the graphics state **(1)** *after* constructing the path **(2)**.

Comment: got it @BrunoLowagie

Comment: @AjayJayavarapu Read the documentation! Do not send LinkedIn invitations to people who don't know you. You only have one chance to make a good first impression. You blew that chance.

Comment: @AjayJayavarapu You blew your second chance to make a good impression by posting a question as a comment to a question that is totally unrelated with what you're asking. Seriously? You should learn how to use the Internet correctly!